# How to read the Browsers window.history for development purposes?

Tags: angular, browser-history

We are writing a large Angular 6 Application and implemented our own routing service (at the moment, we do not use the Angular Router). For some reason, the back and forward buttons in the browser are showing some strange behaviour: the back button works only one time, the forward button doesn't work at all.

To debug the apllication's routing, I would like to see the browsers detailed history. In the Chrome history, I can't find the exact URLs. My idea was to log the state of `window.history` with each call to `navigationAction.navigate()` and, if neccessary, do a `history.replaceState()` or `.pushState()`.

The problem is, that I cannot find a way to read the content of `window.history` due to (obviuos) security reasons. **Is there a way to read the history state for development purposes?**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set `enableTracing` on the `RouterModule` - logs out all Angular routing events. Might help you to debug the problem you're having

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true }
    )
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: We do not use the Angular Router at the moment. Sorry that I didn't quite clarified it - I updated the question.